# Could not find function "."

Tags: r, data.table

I'm playing around with `data.table` and finding that some basic syntax isn't working. I definitely have `data.table` loaded, and here's the data:

```
 DT
    V1 V2      V3 V4
 1:  1  A  0.3408  1
 2:  1  A -0.3795  7
 3:  1  B  0.3408  5
 4:  1  B -0.3795 11
 5:  1  C -0.3795  3
 6:  1  C  0.3408  9
 7:  2  A -0.7460  4
 8:  2  A -0.7033 10
 9:  2  B -0.7033  2
10:  2  B -0.7460  8
11:  2  C -0.7033  6
12:  2  C -0.7460 12
```

Here are the `attributes`

```
> attributes(DT)
$names
[1] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4"

$row.names
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

$class
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"

$.internal.selfref
<pointer: 0x10180cb78>

$sorted
[1] "V1" "V2"
```

And here's all I'm trying:

```
> DT[,.(sum(V1),sd(V3))]
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "."
```

What's wrong with this?

----Added---

Here's my version info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.3.3  data.table_1.9.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.8   memoise_0.2.1  plyr_1.8.2     Rcpp_0.11.6    reshape2_1.4.1 stringr_1.0.0  tools_3.1.2
```

Comment: What version are you using? I believe you need 1.9.4 or higher.

Comment: what do you think it was supposed to do?

Comment: @Massa Used in certain arguments of `DT[...]`, it is a short alias for `list`.

Comment: @hrbrmstr as I said in my question, I definitely have data.table loaded in the environment.

Comment: @sunny you really need to double check that. if it was, it'd work.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I triple-checked before posting this question.

Comment: @sunny Any reason not to reveal the version you're using? You can see it with `sessionInfo()`

Comment: @Frank just added this information to my question.

Comment: @nrussell not sure what version I was running, but I just ran an update and am still getting the same error. I've added the version info to my question.

Comment: I'd show a reproducible example as to why I'm so adamant but this https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/990 (data.table is teh buggy)  makes it impossible to do an `unloadNamespace()` or `detach()` properly enough to do so.

Comment: You're running 1.9.4. `.` as an alias for `list` is only from 1.9.5 onwards. You can install the development version via their GitHub page, see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Comment: @MichaelChirico I'm running 1.9.4 (CRAN) and the syntax works fine _provided_ `data.table` is loaded.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yeah, it was available in 1.9.4 for use in `j`

Comment: @hrbrmstr true, via Github: "Changes in v1.9.4... #6. `.()` can now be used in `j` and is identical to `list()`, for consistency with `i`."

Comment: as you can see from my sessionInfo() I do have data.table loaded.

Comment: To all: I just individually updated data.table (rather than running update.packages() ) and now it's working. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @nrussell's comment about the versioning, I first updated all packages and restarted R, reimported everything etc. That didn't work. But then I individually updated `data.table` (`install.packages("data.table")` and then agreeing to the update rather than `update.packages()` ) and now it's working.

Comment: @summy May i know the reason for deleting your latest question after getting an answer?